# Many conditions in the if function don't work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 fields in my template. I would like the user to see an error message if each field is not filled (all must be filled in).

My template looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="category" class="form-control form-control-emphasized" id="category" placeholder="Wpisz kategorie..." maxlength="200" required>
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control form-control-emphasized" placeholder="Wpisz nazwę..." maxlength="200" required id="id_name">
<textarea name="description" cols="40" rows="3" class="form-control form-control-emphasized" placeholder="Napisz parę słów na temat sprzedawanego produktu..." required id="id_description">
</textarea>
<button onClick="stepThird()">Next step</button>
```

My JavaScript:

```
  function stepThird() {
  var valueCategory = document.getElementById('category');
  var valueName = document.getElementById('id_name');
  var valueDescription = document.getElementById('id_description');
  if (valueCategory.value.length < 2 && valueName.value.length < 2 && valueDescription.value.length < 2 ) {
    alert('All 3 fields must be longer than 2 characters');
  } else {
  alert('Ok, you can go to the next step')
  }}
```

*Embedded on onClick

But my function is not working properly. When the user completes only one field, he passes it to the next step. Why? `&&` - means that all fields must be longer than 2 characters, otherwise an error message should start. Why is this not working properly?

Comment: Can you expand this to a runnable code snippet to observe the behavior?

Comment: If you want to see the error message as soon as _at least_ one of the values is shorter than two characters, then of course you want _OR_. With AND, _all_ of them would have to be shorter at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you should put `||` in your condition, because your condition is satisfied only if **all** inputs are not completed and if a user completes **any** of them the condition won't let you error code to be set, thus letting him/her to proceed.